# Issue Rendering Glass Cycles

Tags: rendering

I'm using version 2.93.6 and the glass in my model is not rendering properly in the final render. It does show up properly in the viewport which is what has me confused. I'm a total blender novice, but I'm using blender mainly to change some materials and get a nice final image of this model I designed.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: render]
[image: viewport]

Comment: please add a screenshot of your glass material's node tree.

Comment: It looks like you have some object hidden from viewport (base mesh?), but not from rendering ... Check if all disabled eye icons have disabled camera icons as well under Outliner editor.